# Get complete HTML contents from Android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, partial

I have a WebView with some web page in it. Now I want to retrieve **complete** HTML contents of what is inside the WebView.

I use loadUrl("javascript:...") and WebView's javascript interface feature to retrieve this HTML using something like this:

- document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML / outerHTML
- document.documentElement.outerHTML
- ...

In each case I receive **partial** HTML contents - exactly first 10000 characters! So my question is - how do I get **complete** HTML content? Is it device-specific and, maybe there are workarounds?

Btw, web pages are created dynamically with javascript - I can't simply download the file from server.

Also, I tried printing HTML contents in javascript with console.log and found exactly the same behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - it was not related to javascript, neither had to do with specific device I tested on.

So, in short, any of those js properties work correctly.